# How to test interaction with JS on a Blazor component using bUnit or any other?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, blazor, blazor-jsinterop, bunit

There is a Blazor component that interacts with JS via `JSRuntime` and back from JS via `dotNetObjectRef`.

The component has an OnInit event which is called with JS using `dotNetObjectRef.invokeMethodAsync("handler")`. It is configured from the DotNet side by calling the JS `addEventListener` method.

The component works, however, during testing with bUnit, the JS code does not run at all. How to make it possible to test this component.

Test code using bUnit :

```cs
    [Fact]
    public async Task Events_ThatEventIsRaised()
    {
        bool isEventRaised = false;

        // Arrange
        using var context = CreateContext();
 
        // Act
        var myComponent = context.RenderComponent<MyComponent>(parameters => parameters
                .Add(p => p.OnInit, e => isEventRaised = true) 
            );

        // Assert
        Assert.True(isEventRaised); 
    }
```

I tried  loading the JS file manually but it didn't work:

```
context.JSInterop.SetupModule("component.js");
```

Comment: Afaik bUnit does not uses a Browser and will not execute any JS. So either Fake that OnInit call or use another (browser based) test platform.

Comment: Correct, bUnit does not use a browser when running tests. It runs entirely in C#.

Answer (score 4):

bUnit includes a fake implementation of Blazors JSInterop. It works very much like Moq and allows you to set up expected calls to your JavaScript and specify responses. Learn more here: https://bunit.dev/docs/test-doubles/emulating-ijsruntime

To emulate JavaScript calling methods in your Blazor components, simply call the methods yourself, e.g.:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Events_ThatEventIsRaised()
{
    bool isEventRaised = false;

    // Arrange
    using var context = CreateContext();
    var myComponent = context.RenderComponent<MyComponent>(parameters => parameters
            .Add(p => p.OnInit, e => isEventRaised = true) 
        );

    // Act
    myComponent.Instance.Handler();

    // Assert
    Assert.True(isEventRaised); 
}
```